# React js switch video sources error comes in Dash.js

Tags: reactjs, mp4, wowza, dash.js

I am working on reactjs project with dashjs for playing video files. when I switch the videos getting following errors in attachView() function.

console [click here for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx92U.png) following code I am using :
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

```
//console.log("nextprops", nextProps);
this.setState({ show: false });
setTimeout(function () { this.setState({ show: true }); }.bind(this), 500)

if (this.state.show && !nextProps.safari && nextProps.videoURL && nextProps.videoURL !== this.props.videoURL) {

    setTimeout(function () {
this.player.reset();
      this.player.attachView(this.video);
      this.player.attachSource(nextProps.videoURL);
      this.setState({ volume: this.player.getVolume() });
   }.bind(this), 2000)

}
```

}

Comment: If only there was a way for you to share the error you are seeing, as text, in the question, with an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

<s>This looks like a bug (or at least a deficiency with the documentation) with dash.js - you should open a new issue at https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues.</s>

**EDIT: This has been fixed as of dash.js v2.8.0.**

In the meantime, for your use case where it looks like `this.video` doesn't change between calls, you can probably remove the calls to `reset` and `attachView` and just call `attachSource` with the new `nextProps.videoURL`. Note that you would obviously still need to call `attachView` (or `initialize`) at least once to attach `this.video`.

Comment: A very similar issue is currently being tracked at https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/2637